# Management Microsoft Azure by Flask

Tags: azure, flask, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I'm developing an Azure Management website that uses Flask.
I googled and found out following sample:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-python-flask-graphapi-web-v2

But this sample is for accessing the Microsoft Graph API, not the Azure Resource Management API.

```
microsoft = oauth.remote_app(
    'microsoft',
    consumer_key='Register your app at apps.dev.microsoft.com',
    consumer_secret='Register your app at apps.dev.microsoft.com',
    request_token_params={'scope': 'offline_access User.Read'},
    base_url='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    authorize_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
)
```

I think that change `base_url` to `https://management.azure.com/` based on the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-api-authentication

But this code didn't work.

Could you let me know that how to use Flask + OAuth2 (supported MSAL) and the Azure Management API?

Alternatively, is there MSAL for Python?

Comment: I want to use 'Azure Active Directory v2.0 endpoint':
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-flows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to Azure AD v2.0 endpoint [restrictions on services and APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations#restrictions-on-services-and-apis). The v2.0 endpoint issues access tokens only for :

> The app that requested the token. An app can acquire an access token for itself, if the logical app is composed of several different components or tiers. To see this scenario in action, check out our Getting Started tutorials.
>
> The Outlook Mail, Calendar, and Contacts REST APIs, all of which are located at https://outlook.office.com. To learn how to write an app that accesses these APIs, see the Office Getting Started tutorials.
>
> Microsoft Graph APIs. You can learn more about Microsoft Graph and the data that is available to you.

So Azure Resource Management API is not currently supported in Azure AD v2.0 endpoint .

Comment: Thank you! I found out this movie:https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/P4031?ocid=player

Answer (score 1):

You can modify that same Flask sample app to use the v1 endpoint by changing the configuration as follows:

```
microsoft = oauth.remote_app(
    'microsoft',
    consumer_key='Register your app at apps.dev.microsoft.com',
    consumer_secret='Register your app at apps.dev.microsoft.com',
    base_url='https://management.azure.com',
    request_token_url=None,
    access_token_method='POST',
    access_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token',
    authorize_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://management.azure.com/'
)
```

Key differences to call out:

- Remove the request_token_parameters piece
- Replace the `base url` to `https://management.azure.com`
- Replace the `authorize_url` with `authorize_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://management.azure.com/'`

You can then call the API as follows:

```
subscriptions = microsoft.get('subscriptions?api-version=2015-01-01')
```

Comment: Thank you! But this is for v1 endpoint...
However I hope run v1 endpoint, so very helpfull your advise!

My latest code:
    microsoft = oauth.remote_app(
        'microsoft',
        consumer_key='<key>',
        consumer_secret='<secret>',
        base_url='https://management.azure.com/',
        request_token_url=None,
        access_token_method='POST',       access_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token',
        authorize_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://management.azure.com/'
)

Comment: Sorry, I failed to update the first code snippet, only called out the alleged differences (which I didn't make). Thanks for the edit, now it's correct.